# closeEntry() of Class ZipOutputStream

Tags: java, java-7, try-catch-finally, try-with-resources, zipoutputstream

I'm writing a code with Java7 and I use the try-with-resources feature. 
When I create an instance of ZipOutputStream. By doing that I no longer have to close the stream in the finally block. The try-with-resources managed that (by the JVM of course).
My question is - what about the use of **closeEntry()**. Should I write this method in my try block or should I delete it and the JVM will close it automatically by the try-with-resources feature just like it does with the method close()?

I'm almost sure that it is not relevant to the try-with-resources (or to the finally block) and I should do it inside my try block and not in the finally block (if I use a regular try-catch-finally), but I want to be sure about it.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

> what about the use of closeEntry(). Should I write this method in my try block or should I delete it and the JVM will close it automatically by the try-with-resources feature just like it does with the method close()?

If you want `closeEntry()` to be invoked, then you should arrange for it to be invoked.  It will not be invoked automatically when the try-with-resources block is exited -- at least not directly.  Nor should it be, for `closeEntry()` logically pairs with `putNextEntry()`, and entering the body of the `try` block does not cause `putNextEntry()` to be invoked.

It is possible that stream closure will subsume the effect of `closeEntry()` if, in fact, an entry is open when it is invoked.  That is not documented, however, so the safest thing to do would be to indeed ensure that `closeEntry()` is invoked after the last entry.  You may also invoke it between entries, but you do not need to do so because `putNextEntry()` is documented to close any open entry before starting a new one.